# how do you represent obstacles in a grid for pathfinding as a graph

Tags: graph-theory, dijkstra, path-finding, a-star

my program compares A* pathfinding algorithm to dijkstra's algorithm showing how informed searches are better than uninformed. in the write up i explained how a grid is actually a graph with equal distance between noded as such that `grid(0,0)` and `grid(0,1)` are nodes, and the moving between them is the edges of the graph.

i also represented it visually.

[image: graph and grid representation]

my question is how would you represent an obstacle in graph form? (An obstacle is defined as a grid Position that cannot be traversed.

would it be a) where the node is unreachable

[image: no edges to obstacle node in directed graph]

or would it be b) where the directions allow an in but not and out, so it should be avoided?

[image: option be where direction only include a to and not a from]

or would it be c) where that node simply does not exist?
[image]

Comment: Or would it be (c) where the entry `(1,1)` simply doesn't exist in the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions (a) and (c) are exactly the same, with (a) taking a little bit larger memory (depending on how you implement the whole problem and model it as a graph). Suggestion (b) is possible if your use-case needs to report that the current action leads to a sink/error/not-allowed state, so if you just need to compare algorithms then I think it is not necessary to consider it.